# Fastlink OAuth Process

Tags: yodlee

Are there any .net sample apps that demonstrate a FastLink integration?

If not, is it possible for your to document the best way to authenticate using OAuth via .net/C# and output the correct iframe urls?

Can you please document this process without pointing me to:

This: https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_and_LAW_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide

Or this: https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_and_LAW_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_Product_Guide

Comment: Could you please be specific what is missing from the provided links? And what specific issues you are facing while using information present on mentioned links?

Comment: I keep getting this error after attempting OAuth and browsing to the fastlink page  ?oauth_token=e9784744d0ff4ce09a47a3c88e15097e&oauth_error_problem=system_error&oauth_error_code=415&gws_rd=ssl

Do you know what this means?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the 'Add Account' FastLink working successfully in the developer portal using C#.

Code is pasted below, I can add more detail if you need it.

```
    public static string GetAddAccountFastLinkUrl()
    {
        var oauthAccessToken = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(GetYodleeRestResult("jsonsdk/OAuthAccessTokenManagementService/getOAuthAccessToken", new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"cobSessionToken", cobSessionToken},
            {"userSessionToken", userSessionToken},
            {"bridgetAppId", "10003200"}
        }));

        var oauth = new OAuth.OAuthBase();
        var nonce = string.Empty;
        var ts = oauth.GenerateTimeStamp();

        var urlParams = "?access_type=oauthdeeplink&displayMode=desktop";
        var baseUrl = "https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/linkAccount.fastlinksb.action";
        var url = new Uri(baseUrl + urlParams);
        var consumerKey = "a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b";
        var consumerSecret = "1ece74e1ca9e4befbb1b64daba7c4a24";
        var token = oauthAccessToken["token"].ToString();
        var tokenSecret = oauthAccessToken["tokenSecret"].ToString();
        var httpMethod = "GET";
        var normalizedUrl = "";
        var normalizedRequestParameters = "";

        var sig = string.Empty;

        while (true)
        {
            nonce = oauth.GenerateNonce();
            sig = oauth.GenerateSignature(url
                , consumerKey
                , consumerSecret
                , token
                , tokenSecret
                , httpMethod
                , ts
                , nonce
                , OAuth.OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1
                , out normalizedUrl
                , out normalizedRequestParameters);
            if (!sig.Contains('+'))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        var fastLinkUrl = normalizedUrl + "?" + normalizedRequestParameters + "&oauth_signature=" + sig;

        return fastLinkUrl;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any Java code for oauth library for similar representation ?

Answer (score 0):

For the error you are receiving:

> I keep getting this error after attempting OAuth and browsing to the
>   fastlink page
>   ?oauth_token=e9784744d0ff4ce09a47a3c88e15097e&oauth_error_problem=system_error&o‌​auth_error_code=415&gws_rd=ssl

If you are already a customer then,I would suggest you to file a Service Request using Yodlee Customer Care tool.

Apart from that here are few suggestions:
Please look out for any extra space or characters while creating OAUTH signature if there would be something unwanted characters or white spaces even then it will not work.